# QOpenGLWidget makeCurrent() doesn't work

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I have a subclass of QOpenGLWidget that looks like this :

```
class MyWidget : public QOpenGLWidget
{ 
    ...
    virtual void initializeGL();
    virtual void resizeGL( int width, int height );
    virtual void paintGL();

    void SetWireframe( bool value );
};
```

SetWireframe function is called by the main window when the checkbox is checked.

From what I've understand, I need to make the context current before my GL functions calls if they are outside of initializeGL, resizeGL and paintGL.

```
void MyWidget::SetWireframe( bool value )
{
    makeCurrent();

    if( value )
        glPolygonMode( GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE );
    else
        glPolygonMode( GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL );

    doneCurrent();
}
```

Without makeCurrent(), glPolygonMode seems to act on the main window and not on my widget, but without this call nothing is done. How to make it work?

( I use GLEW instead of QGLFunctions if that matters )

Edit : When storing the value variable and setting wireframe state in paintGL(), it is working, but I'd like to make it work normally ( using SetWireframe ).

Comment: Is that `SetWireframe` being called after `initializeGL` has been called by Qt?

Comment: Yes. Since it is called each time the checkbox is checked/unchecked.

Comment: Ok, the problem is fixed, I just forgot to uncomment things in paintGL so when I first used makeCurrent(), nothing changed...